# How to show other custom post type other than current post type in a single.php

Tags: custom-post-types

I have my `single-{my custom post type)` page. Here the Current post type is showing. Under that I want to show other Custom post type so that I can navigate to other post type. How to do that. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do a wp_query to get the other post types into your file e.g.

```
<?php
     $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'posttype_name',
      'posts_per_page' => '-1',
      'order' => 'DESC'
     );
     $query = new WP_Query($args);
     while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
      $query->the_post();
          the_title();
     }
     wp_reset_postdata();
     ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it ..Here is the Code

```
<?php
                            $args=array(
    'post_type' => 'my_post_type',
    'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
    'order'=>'ASC',
    'posts_per_page'=> 3, // Number of related posts that will be shown.
    'caller_get_posts'=>1,
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
     the_title();
    the_content();
    endwhile;
    ?>
```